# SD to MicroSD adapter

Tags: hardware-rec, sd-card

I am looking for an adapter that will let me plug a full-size SD card into a micro-SD slot. The adapter probably has a microSD card attached to a cable and then a full-size SD socket. Does anybody know of anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one (extremely expensive);
http://www.aptolink.com/content/sd-microsd-extender-card

Here's another, but it looks like these guys have one, but you have to buy them a 1000 at a time.  Perhaps the part number will turn up on eBay or other sites (PA-TFC1)? http://www.ably.com.tw/main.htm

Looks like a tricky thing to pin down!

Comment: "extremely expensive"??? daylight robbery is more like it :) +1